# Why does printing this character value produce a number?

Tags: c++, loops, random

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  // initialize the computer's random number generator
  srand(time(0)); rand();

  // declare variables
  char c1;
  char c2;
  char c3;

  c1 = 'R';
  c2 = 'P';
  c3 = 'S';

  // start loop
  while (true)
  {

    // determine computer's choice
    int result = rand() % 3; // 0 or 1 or 2

    if (result == 0) 
      result = c1;

    if (result == 1) 
      result = c2;

    if (result == 2) 
      result = c3;

    // prompt for, and read, the human's choice

    char humanChoice;
    cout << "Rock, Paper, or Scissors? [R/P/S or Q] ";
    cin >> humanChoice;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);

    // if human wants to quit, break out of loop
    if (humanChoice == 'Q') break;


    // print results
    cout << result << endl;
    cout << humanChoice << endl;

  // end loop
  }

  // end program 



  return 0;
}
```

What's up guys? I am on my first step of my midterm project which is to create a rock-paper-scissors game. This is just the beginning, and I am far from done, but I already have run into an error. When I compile and run this, I am getting that the compute has chosen the number 83, when it must be either r p or s. Does anyone see where I went wrong with this?

Comment: Your result is an int, not a char.

Comment: *Unrelated to your question*: Never say `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. In your case, you are needlessly flushing the output stream after printing `result`.

Answer (score 2):

**result** is of type **int** (and as such it is being interpreted as a decimal number by cout), you mean it to have type **char** (so that it is intepretted as a text character).

Also you have "overloaded" **result** to first hold the value of `rand() % 3` and then second the character value.  In general, it's best to keep variables separate for readability - the optimizer can figure out to reuse the same storage for them to save stack space.

Try this:

```
char result;

switch (rand() % 3)
{
case 0: result = c1; break;
case 1: result = c2; break;
case 2: result = c3; break;
}
```

Comment: C++ has a lot of implicit casts.  You are seeing the ASCII value.

Comment: @Mike: Not necessarily, but most likely. :)

Answer (score 0):

`result` is `int`, which will store (and print) the numeric representation of the character you assign to it.

There are multiple ways of fixing this, one would be to simply change `result` to `char`. You can still store numbers in it (limited to 0-255) and will have the correct output.

The better way, imho, would be a slight refactoring to first get the human input and then act upon the computers choice (preferrably with a `switch`).

Answer (score 0):

The 83 refers to the unicode value of 's'. Since result is an int, when you assign the char 's' to result, it gets cast to an int. Therefore, it outputs 83.

Try using a different variable for the output. For example:

```
char response;
if(result==0)
    response = c1;
...
cout << response << end1
```

Comment: Thank you guys, really appreciate it!. I was so confused as to where the number 83 was coming from hha.

Answer (score 0):

The input you're taking is of a char type. Casting that to an integer will give you the ASCII value of the char in question. The ascii value for P is 80, R is 82 and S is 83.

You'd be better off using an enum with a switch-case statement :

```
enum Choices { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS };
```

Answer (score 0):

The cout << thing is overloaded. Behaves differently for int and for char. If it is an int whatever is the type of the variable then the output will be a number, if it is a char (character) (we don't care about the size, but we care about the type) then the output will be a character. So in order to fix this the result variables type has to be a char as previously was mentioned.